# Why the line plot is not grouping correctly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have the following csv file:

```
class,quantity,time
mongoclientsmall,1000,29.6
mongoclientsmall,10000,236.3
mongoclientsmall,100000,2388.4
mongoclientsmall,200000,4766.7
mongoosesmall,1000,30.7
mongoosesmall,10000,232.2
mongoosesmall,100000,2342.6
mongoosesmall,200000,4744.9
mongoclientbig,1000,31.1
mongoclientbig,10000,238.5
mongoclientbig,100000,2404.4
mongoclientbig,200000,4795.5
mongoosebig,1000,30.8
mongoosebig,10000,239
mongoosebig,100000,2356.6
mongoosebig,200000,4721
```

This has four classes, but when I plot with the following command, it shows a plot with two lines, why?

The command to plot:

```
difftime_update <- read.table("./difftime-update.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")

ggplot(data=difftime_update, aes(x=quantity,y=time,group=class)) +
geom_line()
```

Comment: Lines overlap each others that's why you only see 2 lines. Add `color = class` to see them easier

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. The values associated with each class are just really close to one another at each x-axis value. In addition to colour, you can also add `+facet_wrap(class)` to see the separate lines more distinctly.

Comment: Owww, this didn't pass in my mind, how can  i see it? Thanks guys, a lot of hours doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `colour` not `group`.

```
difftime_update %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=quantity,y=time, colour=class)) +
  geom_line()
```

This worked for me.